# Fetching more data from trained models

Tags: ios, tensorflow

I have got a pre-trained tensorflow model which can recognize particular object which are same having different colour but when the camera recognizes the object it is showing the name of object but i need to get the colour also when it recognizes. how can i achieve that ?

I am currently trying to create an ios app with the tutorial given in [tensorflow.org/lite/demo_ios](https://tensorflow.org/lite/demo_ios) in which i need to integrate the above mentioned trained model. It should allow me to show additional parameters like colour, type when it recognize the object. currently it is giving the name of that object only.

Comment: please share code to get helped. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am currently trying to create an ios app with the tutorial given in https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/demo_ios inwhich i need to integrate the above mentioned trained model. It should allow me to show additional parameters like colour, type when it recognize the object. currently it is giving the name of that object only.@Maelig